# generate arrays from string

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, json, merge

When I run :

```
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result3)) { 

echo json_encode($r); 

}
```

the results is :

```
{"test1":"1","test2":"2","test3":"3","test4":"4"}

{"test1":"5","test2":"5","test3":"7","test4":"8"}
```

**my question is :
How can I create arrays from the results above knowing that the number of lines is not fixed, it may change depend on the data. So, I could make changes to the arrays and parse it in a format similar to this :**

```
["test1"=>"1","5"],

["test2"=>"2","6"], 

["test3"=>"3","7"], 

["test4"=>"4", "8"]
```

Thanks!!

Comment: please `print_r($result3);` then put the result over here whatever it display its easy to help it out

Comment: @Jalpesh: `$result3` is (presumably) a MySQL resource identifier.

Comment: @kech: One assumes that the change in the second value for `test2` (from `5` in the current output to `6` in the desired output) is merely a typo?  In any event, each array element has its own key so the desired output as shown doesn't really make sense: perhaps you are instead after something like `{ "test1" : [1,5], "test2" : [2,5], ... }` ?

Comment: @eggyal Well, that's what I'm guessing as well...

Comment: @Jalpesh: yes - it's a MySQL resource identifier.
print_r($r) gaves:
 ( [test1] => 1 [test2] => 2 [test3] => 3 [test4] => 4 ) Array ( [test1] => 5 [test2] => 6 [test3] => 7 [test4] => 8 )

Comment: @eggyal: yes it's typo, sorry for the confusion.
yes - that is the format I'm after and I will change after that.
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Try this :**

```
<?php

$arr = array();

while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result3)) 
{ 
    foreach ($r as $index=>$item)
    {
        $arr[$index][]=$item;
    }
}

?>
```

And to encode as JSON *(after re-arranging the array)* :

```
$arr = json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: +1 For completeness, I'd also show where you perform the `json_encode()` here (i.e. after exiting the `while` loop).

Comment: @eggyal IF he actually wants it as Json. (my guess is that he used `json` only as a means of showing as the output)

Comment: Perhaps... but the question is tagged [tag:javascript] and [tag:json], so my guess is not.

Comment: If I was to be really pedantic, I'd point out that your edit still doesn't clarify exactly *where* the call to `json_encode()` should be placed.  But I'm not gonna do that.  ;)

Comment: when I run  print_r($arr[$index]); inside foreach
I get the values without the keys :
( [0] => 1 ) Array ( [0] => 2 ) Array ( [0] => 3 ) Array ( [0] => 4 ) 
Array ( [0] => 5 ) Array ( [0] => 6 ) Array ( [0] => 7 ) Array ( [0] => 8 )
wherever I put $arr = json_encode($arr); inside or outside the while loop, when I run print_r($arr); it dispay ( [test1] => Array ( [0] => 5 ) [test2] => Array ( [0] => 6 ) [test3] => Array ( [0] => 7 ) [test4] => Array ( [0] => 8 ) )

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon, sorry about tha, I want just to ask if you have any idea bout how to format the result to parse it like 
["test1"=>"1","5"],["test2"=>"2","6"], ["test3"=>"3","7"], ["test4"=>"4", "8"]? Thanks!

Comment: @kech Do you mean `["test1"=>["1","5"]],...`? If this is what you want... putting a `json_encode($r)` JUST after the `while` loop, would do it...

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon I believe that I'm doing something wrong and I couldn't find it. this is my code, 
$arr = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result3)) {
 foreach ($r as $index=>$item)
    {
        $arr[$index][]=$item;
        print_r($arr[$index]);
    }
} 
$json = json_encode($r);
echo $json;

can you see anything wrong with it?
Thank you!

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon,  my bad, my sever was crashing, so I couldn't refresh my page to display the new results, last thing, 
How can I remove the quotes and the brackets from the results and keep the format [key1, value1, value5],[key2, value2, value5],...?
Thank you!

Comment: @kech Phewww, glad to hear that, coz I simply couldn't find anything wrong with that. If you want to remove the quotes, a `$finalArray = str_replace("\"","",$final_string_after_json_encoding)` would work, but I'm not sure this is what you'd want, 'coz it'd turn it into invalid json. If you still want to remove the quotes from the numeric parts though, that would be possible by changing `$arr[$index][]=$item;` into `$arr[$index][]=intvalue($item);`. Hope it helps!

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon
you are right! I have to keep quotes, 
the "Intvalue" function is exactly what I was looking for !!
Now is the last step, how can I display ['key', value1, value5],.. just the formating quotes and breaks. and that should be it!
Thanks a lot for your help! I'm glad, I got help from someome like you! Thanks for being patient!
kech

Comment: @kech Just saw your message; you mean you want to display `['key', val1, val2, val3]` instead of `['key'=>[val1,val2,val3]]`? Why is that? Are we still talking about the string representation of that (initially) json-encoded data?